# How to test service calls using mockwebserver that contains redirection?

Tags: android, robolectric, android-testing, okhttp, mockwebserver

I am using mockwebserver to mock request and response for my android app. I am testing a login feature which goes through a series of 4 service calls.

1. Get access token
2. Re-direct
3. Get user info (different base url)
4. Get some other stuff (original base url)

I am trying to mock the response of the redirected call. Here is my code:

```
@Test
public void testSuccessfulLogin() throws Exception {
    // Post
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse()
            .setResponseCode(HTTP_OK)
            .setBody(getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), "access_token.json")));

    // Redirect
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(HTTP_MOVED_TEMP));

    // GET user info
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(HTTP_OK).setBody(getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), "userinfo.json")));

    // GET some other stuff
    server.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(HTTP_OK)
            .setBody(getStringFromFile(getInstrumentation().getContext(), "sts.json")));

    // Init call
    loginWithoutWaiting(Data.serviceLoginUsername, Data.serviceLoginPassword);

    // Debug (need to loop 4 times to get all 4 call paths)
    RecordedRequest request = server.takeRequest();
    request.getPath();
}
```

My test fails at the Redirect code. I cannot login. I have found some hints [here](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/f91f97795b6fc3ccfec3d2ec4ea46abe733012df/okhttp-tests/src/test/java/okhttp3/CookiesTest.java#L214) but I do not fully understand what is going on, thus can't make it work at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out to be quite easy. In the call that makes redirect, create a new mocked response with response code 302 and header with location url. The next call will use that location url.

```
case "/userinfo":
return new MockResponse().setResponseCode(HTTP_MOVED_TEMP).setHeader("Location", "/api-test.com/users");

case "/api-test.com/users":
return new MockResponse().setBody("{}")).setResponseCode(HTTP_OK);
```